# C pointer to string returning warning

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
int ver(unsigned char** v) {
    unsigned char str1[] = "1.0.2";
    strcpy(v, str1);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unsigned char s[10];
    ver(s);
    printf("version = %s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following warning that the pointer differs in signedness. Can you please advise.

Comment: What do you expect from your program?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: ... or pointer-pointers.

Comment: Which warning?? Why do you think an extra `*` does **not** make a difference?

Comment: Consider removing a star from the declaration/definition of `ver`. It is possible that your program may stop seg-faulting or delivering gibberish if you do.

Comment: `int ver(unsigned char ** v){` and `ver(s);` does not actually match, you know.

Comment: A pointer does not have a signedness. Please state the **exact** warning and line/position. To avoid further repetition, learn [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Change the declaration of `ver` to:

```
int ver(unsigned char * v)
```

I.e. get rid of one of the `*` characters.

Answer (score 1):

Warning about signedness is because `strcpy` and `printf("%s")` expect a `char*`, but you are passing `unsigned char*`

Also `int ver(unsigned char ** v)` should be `int ver(char* v)`

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the warning:

`strcpy()` expects a `signed char*`, and is called with a `unsigned char*`.

But there should be other warnings as well:

Function `ver()` expects a pointer to a pointer:

```
int ver(unsigned char ** v){
```

`ver(s)` sends a single pointer to `char`:

```
unsigned char s[10];
ver(s);
```

To solve, you can change the code to:

```
int ver(char *v) {

    char str1[] = "1.0.2";
    strcpy(v, str1);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char s[10];
    ver(s);
    printf("version = %s", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `strcpy(*v, str1)`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Updated

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is this :

```
int ver(unsigned char ** v)
```

You have to change the function to that :

```
int ver(unsigned char * v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 fixes:

1) Follow what others told you about the method declaration, changing to "`int ver(unsigned char* v) {`" ;

2) Just include `<string.h>` at your code.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int ver(unsigned char* v) {
    unsigned char str1[] = "1.0.2";
    strcpy(v, str1);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unsigned char s[10];
    ver(s);
    printf("version = %s", s);
    return 0;
}
```